# What is the Python equivalent of Comparables in Java?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of the following form:

```
{ <Category('Simulate', 'False', 'False', 'False', 'INTERMEDIATE')>: {'link': u'/story/4/tvb-adapters-simulator-simulatorAdapter/SimulatorAdapter', 'name': u'Simulate'}, 
  <Category('View Results', 'True', 'False', 'True', 'INTERMEDIATE')>: {'link': '/story/step/3', 'name': u'View Results'}, 
  <Category('Analyze', 'True', 'False', 'False', 'FINAL')>: {'link': '/story/step/2', 'name': u'Analyze'}}
```

Category is a class representing an instance from a database. Now I have the following instance:

```
    <Category('Analyze', 'True', 'False', 'False', 'FINAL')>
```

Now this is not the same instance. By this I mean, I get all the values from the database and create the dictionary. Then after a while I get an id and retrieve the instance from the database. Now they are not the same objects. I now have to check if it's in the dictionary, but:

```
instance in disctionary
```

Will return false. Now I could go the ugly way and iterate over the dictionary checking if all the values match, however does Python have a more clever way to do this? I mean something like the equivalent of Comparable in Java?

Comment: I fail to recognize this as valid Python. What is this `<Category(...)>`?

Comment: That's his pretty-printed dict, and it's custom to use angle brackets in the repr() of a class.

Comment: @pyroscope: Thanks! Learning something new every day...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First: use `True` and `False` (boolean properties) instead of `'True'` and `'False'` (string properties).

Generally, you can make everything comparable in Python. You just have to define specific methods (like `__eq__`, `__lt__`, etc.) for your class.

So, let's say I want to compare instances of class A, and the comparison should be just case-insensitive string comparison of `s` member:

```python
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, s=''):
        self.s = s

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.s.lower() == other.s.lower()

a = A('aaaa')
b = A('AAAA')
print a == b # prints True
b = A('bbbb')
print a == b # prints False
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using instances of `Category` (e.g. `Category('Analyze', 'True', 'False', 'False', 'FINAL')`) as the keys in your dictionary,
it sounds like you should be using the associated tuple (e.g. `('Analyze', 'True', 'False', 'False', 'FINAL')`).

If you really do want to use instance of `Category` as the keys in the dictionary, you'll need to define both the [`__hash__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) and `__eq__` methods.
For example:

```
class Category(object):
    def __init__(self,*args):
        self.args=args
    def __hash__(self):
        # Note that this assumes that Category's hash value is immutable
        # i.e. self.args does not change.
        return hash(self.args)
    def __eq__(self,other):
        return self.args == other.args

a=Category('Analyze', 'True', 'False', 'False', 'FINAL')
b=Category('Analyze', 'True', 'False', 'False', 'FINAL')

mydict={a:1}
```

`a` and `b` are distinct instances, so they have different `id`s, but their hash values are the same:

```
assert id(a) != id(b)
assert hash(a)==hash(b)
```

This shows `b` is an acceptable key in `mydict`:

```
print(mydict[a])
# 1
print(mydict[b])
# 1
```

PS. Don't bother with `__cmp__`. [In Python 3](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons):

> The cmp() function should be treated as gone, and the `__cmp__()`
>   special method is no longer supported. Use `__lt__()` for sorting,
>   `__eq__()` with `__hash__()`, and other rich comparisons as needed.

Comment: I am using the tuples that was just the result of a preety print.

Answer (score 2):

As you can apparently put your category instances into a dict, you must have overwritten `__hash__` already. All you need now is `__eq__`:

```
class Category(object):
    # you must have overwritten `__hash__` like this already
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.attr1, self.attr2, ... ))

    # now you just need tis
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, Category) and \
               (self.attr1, self.attr2, ... ) == (other.attr1, other.attr2, ... )
```

What you should really do is throw that whole class away and use a `collections.namedtuple` instead:

```
Category = collections.namedtuple('Category', 'attr1 attr2 attr3')
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be shortcuts, like using tuples, but the generic answer to your question is: implement `__eq__()` for your class, so that cmp() will use it instead of testing for identity.

Answer (score 1):

For `in` and other comparison operators to work, you have to implement `__hash__` and  `__cmp__` (or the "rich" comparison methods like `__eq__`). See the [Python reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html).